# Using shared libraries with dlopen - shared object cannot find symbol exported by the loading program

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dlsym

So, I have a following example I'm trying to run.

header.h

```
extern "C" {
        void registerfunc();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*register_func)();

void registerfunc() {
    cout << "register func has been called" << endl;
}

int main() {
    void* lib_handle = dlopen("./test/test.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);

    if(lib_handle == NULL){
            cout << "no such lib:" << dlerror() <<endl;
            return 0;
    }

    register_func reg = (register_func)dlsym(lib_handle, "test");

    if(reg == NULL){
            cout << "Cannot load symbol" <<  dlerror() << endl;;
    } else {
            reg();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it is compiled with following makefile

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp -ldl
```

then, i want to use registerfunc from my own so, which is written in the following way:

main.h:

```
extern "C"
{
    void test();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
#include "../header.h"

void test() {
    registerfunc();
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp -fPIC -shared -o test.so
```

When I compile it this way and run a.out (output of first main), I get:

```
 no such lib: ./test/test.so: undefined symbol: registerfunc
```

However, if i compile a.out and test.so using following commands:

```
a.out -> g++ -g -fPIC -shared main.cpp -ldl
test.so -> g++ -g main.cpp -fPIC -shared -o test.so ../a.out
```

then I'm getting a segmentation fault with following backtrace (gdb -ex run a.out):

```
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
```

That leaves me kinda stumped, as to how make test.so call something that is defined by it's callee. Could you, please, help?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three separate problems here:

- The smaller one is that you have two files named `main.cpp`, and it's not entirely clear which command refers to which file in your question.
- The bigger problem is that you are expecting `test.so` to bind to `registerfunc` in a.out, but the function is not *exported* from `a.out` *unless* some shared library participating in the link references that function, *or* you link with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` (which exports *all* functions). This is the real solution.

  You can see which functions are exported from your `a.out` with this command:

  `nm -D a.out | grep ' T '`
- Finally, when you do this:

  `a.out -> g++ -g -fPIC -shared main.cpp -ldl`

  you are actually creating a shared library (named `a.out`), not an executable. Running such a shared library as if it were an executable leads to the crash you've observed.